# how to get the 10 most frequent strings in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list that has 93 different strings. I need to find the 10 most frequent strings and the return must be in order from most frequent to least frequent.

```
mylist = ['"and', '"beware', '`twas', 'all', 'all', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'arms', 'as', 'as', 'awhile', 'back', 'bandersnatch', 'beamish', 'beware', 'bird', 'bite', 'blade', 'borogoves', 'borogoves', 'boy', 'brillig']
 # this is just a sample of the actual list.
```

I dont have the newest version of python and cannot use a counter.

Answer (score 16):

You could use a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the [`collections` module](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) to do this.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(mylist)
```

Then doing `c.most_common(10)` returns

```
[('and', 13),
 ('all', 2),
 ('as', 2),
 ('borogoves', 2),
 ('boy', 1),
 ('blade', 1),
 ('bandersnatch', 1),
 ('beware', 1),
 ('bite', 1),
 ('arms', 1)]
```

Comment: This is it. No more beating around the bush.

Comment: i dont have the newest version of python and cannot use a counter

Comment: @KeelyAranyos counter was introduced in Python 2.4 - what version are you using?

Comment: @burhan: Counter was introduced in python 2.7, not python 2.4.  I believe the OP is using 2.6.5.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I skipped the table where it lists various versions for each module in collections. I apologize.

Comment: @KeelyAranyos The Python docs link to a Py2.5 and Py2.6 backport of *collections.Counter* .  All you need to do is cut and paste the code:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

Answer (score 3):

David's answer is the best - but if you are using a version of Python that does not include Counter from the collections module (which was introduced in Python 2.7), you can use [this implementation](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/) of a counter class that does the same thing. I suspect that it would be slower than the module, but will do the same thing.

Comment: Counter wasn't included in Python 2.4, but in 2.7. It says so in the docs - http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer to reflect the correct version. However, the solution provided works pre-2.7.

Comment: Cool - This snippet is written by Raymond Hettinger (author of a lot of the stuff in collections), and is much like the 2.7 source. Good find. :)

Answer (score 3):

David's solution is the best.

But probably more for fun than anything, here is a solution that does not import any module:

```
dicto = {}

for ele in mylist:
    try:
        dicto[ele] += 1
    except KeyError:
        dicto[ele] = 1

top_10 = sorted(dicto.iteritems(), key = lambda k: k[1], reverse = True)[:10]
```

Result:

```
>>> top_10
[('and', 13), ('all', 2), ('as', 2), ('borogoves', 2), ('boy', 1), ('blade', 1), ('bandersnatch', 1), ('beware', 1), ('bite', 1), ('arms', 1)]
```

EDIT:

Answering the follow up question:

```
new_dicto = {}

for val, key in zip(dicto.itervalues(), dicto.iterkeys()):

    try:
        new_dicto[val].append(key)
    except KeyError:
        new_dicto[val] = [key]

alph_sorted = sorted([(key,sorted(val)) for key,val in zip(new_dicto.iterkeys(), new_dicto.itervalues())], reverse = True)
```

Result:

```
>>> alph_sorted
[(13, ['and']), (2, ['all', 'as', 'borogoves']), (1, ['"and', '"beware', '`twas', 'arms', 'awhile', 'back', 'bandersnatch', 'beamish', 'beware', 'bird', 'bite', 'blade', 'boy', 'brillig'])]
```

The words that show up once are sorted alphabetically, if you notice some words have extra quotation marks in them.

EDIT:

Answering another follow up question:

```
top_10 = []

for tup in alph_sorted:
    for word in tup[1]:
        top_10.append(word)
        if len(top_10) == 10:
            break
```

Result:

```
>>> top_10
['and', 'all', 'as', 'borogoves', '"and', '"beware', '`twas', 'arms', 'awhile', 'back']
```

Comment: how then would you be able to just get the words and for the words that have the same number, how would you put them in alphabetical order

Comment: how would you get the top 10 of the alph sorted

Comment: @KeelyAranyos I edited my post to answer your second question, hopefully it gives you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `Counter` as the modified version of the question requests

Changed to use `heap.nlargest` as suggested by @Duncan

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> mylist = ['"and', '"beware', '`twas', 'all', 'all', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'arms', 'as', 'as', 'awhile', 'back', 'bandersnatch', 'beamish', 'beware', 'bird', 'bite', 'blade', 'borogoves', 'borogoves', 'boy', 'brillig']
>>> c = defaultdict(int)
>>> for item in mylist:
        c[item] += 1


>>> [word for word,freq in nlargest(10,c.iteritems(),key=itemgetter(1))]
['and', 'all', 'as', 'borogoves', 'boy', 'blade', 'bandersnatch', 'beware', 'bite', 'arms']
```

Comment: i do not have the newest version of python and cannot use a counter

Comment: Do you have `defaultdict`? Try `from collections import defaultdict`, if so I can write a quick solution using that.

Comment: There is a solution using `defaultdict`

Comment: it is saying the last line, the line starting with [word for word...., is invalid syntax

Comment: it is working now, just that way i typed it in made it bring up an error, thank you!!

Comment: No worries but look at the response by @burhan as it is more efficient if you can get that to work.

Comment: for better performance just update your answer to use `heapq.nlargest()` instead of sorting all the results.

Comment: Good advice, I have changed it to use heapq

Answer (score 1):

In case your Python Version does not support Counter, you can do the way Counter is implemented

```
>>> import operator,collections,heapq
>>> counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for elem in mylist:
    counter[elem]+=1        
>>> heapq.nlargest(10,counter.iteritems(),operator.itemgetter(1))
[('and', 13), ('all', 2), ('as', 2), ('borogoves', 2), ('boy', 1), ('blade', 1), ('bandersnatch', 1), ('beware', 1), ('bite', 1), ('arms', 1)]
```

If you see the Counter Class, it creates a dictionary of the occurrence of all the elements present in the Iterable
It then puts the data in an heapq, key is the value of the dictionary and retrieves the nargest